# Magento returns 404 error on all browsers except Firefox

Tags: browser, magento, xampp, http-status-code-404

I've set up Magento on a local XAMPP installation and started developing a theme.
Everything works OK on Firefox, the browser I usually use for development. However, on all other browsers, all I get when accesing the page is a 404 Error "Page not found" shown using Magento's default theme.

I should mention that I am not accessing it using the "http://localhost/sitename" address. I have created a virtual host so that I access the site by going directly to "www.sitename.com", even though it's hosted locally (i did this so that I can configure Magento using the destination URL)

Any help would be appreciated, I really don't understand why this would behave differently on other browsers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same error after I deactivated other languages in backend.

My solution: change the numbers of sorter to 1, 2, ... in the stores with deactivated languages (in "manage stores").

Answer (score -1):

Please delete your cache files located at var/cache folder.Or disable caching feature in magento admin pannel. Please check it after that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The Cache feature was already disabled. I deleted the file in var/cache and nothing changed. What I can't understand is why this would be browser-dependent.

Comment: It's installed locally on my dev machine, I mentioned that in the OP.

Comment: okay. Which is your magento version?.Did you set base url in admin side?

Comment: I'm running Magento 1.5.1.0. I set the base URL when I installed Magento, I checked now and it seems ok.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I checked the base URL and that seems ok...the problem is still there. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Did you update the indexing in admin side?.If not please update it. After that clear your browser cache and retest it.

Comment: I did update it, did it again now and no change. Maybe there's a problem with my server configuration....

Comment: Can you post your Url here. i would like to check it?.Did you enabled Use Web Server Rewrites in admin site. If so please set it as no after that reindex  the application .after that check it

Comment: Yes, it's working perfectly in Firefox.  I should also mention that I can get into the admin section in the other browsers. It's only the frontend that doesn't work.

Comment: OK, I've found a way to fix it but I don't know why it works. If I visit the page http://www.sitename.com/?___store=storename then it starts working normally, and I can visit http://www.sitename.com and it will work. I have to do this for every browser.  I have two store views, maybe I missed a configuration option regarding store views?