# Magento 404 error page frontend

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I noticed that Magento throw back a 404 error when trying to access the website from other locations. This only happenes on frontend. Backend can be accessible from all over the world. I don't know what's wrong. 
I can access the website just normally without any problems! I can access the website even at home without no issues!
The Website is: borika.de 
No restrictions have been noticed. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check could you make a condition of your `index.php` or try to replace with another same version `index.php` may be it will help

Comment: I did that. No result. I've checked the website on apple devices. The frontend is accessible from any apple device (From different locations) but not on android devices and on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I recently deactivated other languages. This was the problem! This is the only solution that worked for me: [Magento returns 404 error on all browsers except Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408487/magento-returns-404-error-on-all-browsers-except-firefox).